# Onclick div add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a class when clicking on a a tag inside a div.
When clicking on the  I want to add the class "show".

I use this HTML:

```
<div class="liveChatContainer online">
<div class="actions">
<span class="item title">Need help?</span>
<a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Chat</a>
<a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Call</a>
<a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Email</a>
</div>
<a href="#" class="liveChatLabel">Contact</a>
</div>
```

See the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wLze4rf/2/

Comment: what you want ?to add class show in anchor tag when its clicked.

Comment: @imGaurav Clicking on the anchor tag, it needs to add class to the "liveChatContainer online". Clicking outside the entire <div "liveChatContainer online"> it needs to remove the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your fiddle, i think this is what you want to do. On click the class gets added and on another click (anywhere on the page) it gets removed.

```
$(".liveChatLabel").click(function(){
    $(".liveChatContainer").addClass("show");
});

$('html').click(function() {
    $(".liveChatContainer.show").removeClass("show");
});

$('.liveChatContainer').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wLze4rf/11/)

Comment: Thanks! And clicking outside the <div "liveChatContainer online">, I also want to remove the class

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last question, how can I run this code in no conflict, because it is conflicting with other jQuery.

Comment: can you tell me with what is is conflicting?

Comment: It breaks down all the other jQuery on my site. So can I run it in no conflict mode?

Comment: Hmm.. hard to say what's the error without seeing more of the code. :/

Comment: Already found the problem! Thanks! One last question, because now the div does not remove the class when clicking on the <a>. I want to remove the class "show" clicking on the <a> and also outside the entire div.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add jQuery library.
2. Use this script:

   `$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.liveChatContainer a').click(function() {
           $('.actions a').removeClass('show');
           $(this).addClass('show');
           return false;
       });
   });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  $('.liveChatContainer').removeClass('show');
});

$('.liveChatContainer a').click(function(e) {
  $('.liveChatContainer').addClass('show');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.liveChatContainer').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.show {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="liveChatContainer online">
  <div class="actions">
    <span class="item title">Need help?</span>

    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Chat</a>

    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Call</a>

    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Email</a>

  </div>
  <a href="#" class="liveChatLabel">Contact</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="liveChatContainer" class="liveChatContainer online">
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="item title">Need help?</span>
        <a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Chat</a>
        <a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Call</a>
        <a href="/test"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>Email</a>
    </div>
<a id="liveChatLabel" href="#" class="liveChatLabel">Contact</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#liveChatLabel').click(
        function(){ 
            $('.actions a').removeClass('show'); 
            $('#liveChatContainer').toggleClass('show'); 
            return false;       
        }); 
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#liveChatContainer");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wLze4rf/9/)

Comment: Thanks! And clicking outside the <div "liveChatContainer online">, I also want to remove the class

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last question, how can I run this code in no conflict, because it is conflicting with other jQuery.

Comment: $.noConflict(); https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ but you really should never have 2 jQuery on one page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used toggle to add and remove the class, here's a fiddle of it:
http://jsfiddle.net/8wLze4rf/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var button = $('.liveChatContainer');

button.on("click",function(){

button.toggleClass('show');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute("class","actions"); to your link in java script